# RadAjaxPanel version of UpdatePanel.Update()?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, telerik, radajaxmanager

What can I do with the RadAjaxPanel to force a partial postback and refresh/update all the controls inside it?  I used to use an UpdatePanel and call .Update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you can call the ajaxRequest() method of the ajax panel. A similar setup is demonstrated in the following article:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxinteractionbetweenpanels.html

Answer (score 4):

I found [this topic](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxinteractionbetweenpanels.html) in the Telerik online docs which pretty much mimics the UpdatePanel.Update() method of the MS Update Panels.

Dick

Answer (score 4):

I would recomend you to use the `RadAjaxManager`.

It is much more flexible than the `RadAjaxPanel`.
The idea is that you define a "triggering control" and than controls that are affected.

I'm not sure what triggers your "force a partial postback" - but if I assume that it is a button than you can a script like this:

```
function FireButton(){

$find("<%=RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("IDofTheButton");
}
```

And in the manager ajaxsettings you add the button as trigger, as well as the controls you want to update as "affected controls".

Comment: I am looking to do this server-side within a method call.